# How can a subpage inherit the style of the parent on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I am designing a theme where every page has a different text, background and other elements' color. I was able to style every single page (and post category related) with these:

```
 <?php if ( is_home() || is_search() || is_archive ()) 
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif( is_category( 'Turismo a Bra' ) || is_page('Turismo a Bra')) 
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/turismo-a-bra.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />      
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Eventi') || is_page('Eventi'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/eventi.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Arte e Cultura') || is_page('Arte e Cultura'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/arte-e-cultura.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } elseif ( is_category ('Enogastronomia')|| is_page('Enogastronomia'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/enogastronomia.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } elseif ( is_category ('Natura')|| is_page('Natura'))
    {
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/natura.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <?php } else {  ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

The problem comes when I have (and i have a lot) of subpages. I want them to be styled as their parents. I though that WP had the is_sub_page(#), but no luck.

Do you know what I should add in the condition to make header understand when it is dealing with a subpage and, in that case, get the ID of the parent and based on that style the page.

I am a novice with php and wordpress, it makes sense in my head, but i dont know how to phrase it.

Thanks a lot, an example is [here](http://www.museidibra.it/prova/turismo-a-bra/)(the subpages are in the upper right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the post decends from a page with a certain category or page title then you could get its parent and check, eg:

```
in_category( 'Turismo a Bra', $post->post_parent )
```

As you already have a lot of code and you are doing this multiple times it may be best to encapsulate your entire check within a function:

```
function needs_style( $style, $the_post ){
    $needs_style = false;
    //check details of this post first
    if( $the_post->post_title == $style ){        //does the same as in_page()
        $needs_style = true;
    } 
    elseif( in_category( $style, $the_post ) ){
        $needs_style = true;
    }
    //otherwise check parent if post has one - this is done recursively 
    elseif( $the_post->post_parent ){
        $the_parent = get_post( $the_post->post_parent );
        $needs_style = needs_style( $style, $the_parent );
    }
    return $needs_style; 
}
```

So your code would look something like:

```
if ( is_home() || is_search() || is_archive ()) { 
    //set stylesheet
}
elseif( needs_style( 'Turismo a Bra', $post ) ) {
    //set stylesheet
}
elseif( needs_style( 'Eventi', $post ) ) {
    //set stylesheet
}
```